# Cocos2D/3D: How to generate and load compressed texture?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures, cocos3d

I'm messing around with PVRTexTool GUI, but only the uncompressed 32 bit texture is shown correctly by the app. I've tried so far all OpenGL ES 2.0 formats

[image]

and some OpenGL ES 1.0

[image]

...but some won't load and others are shown in black.

I'm loading the texture with this code

```
// load texture
CC3Texture* texture = [CC3Texture textureFromFile:@“my_texture.pvr”];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `CC3DemoMashUpScene addSkyBox` method.

In there, you can uncomment the line that loads the `Skybox.pvr` file. You'll also need to uncomment the line in the `initializeScene` method that invokes the `addSkyBox` method.

`Skybox.pvr` is a cube-map texture, containing six compressed PVRTC 2bpp textures. You can use the PVRTexTool to open this texture and compare it to the textures you are trying to load.

Comment: Wierd, the clotest format to Skybox.pvr CC3DemoMashUpScene is PVRTC 2bpp, Unsigned Normalized Byte, Linear RGB, Without MIPMaps, but the texture metadata is saved with 39 bytes instead of 24, maybe it's a new format in PVRTexTool v 4.1.3

Comment: It turned out that PVRTC I needs 9 mipmaps otherwise the texture will load but render in black

Answer (score 3):

The code to load the texture is ok, but not all formats generated by PVRTexTool are supported.

The supported formats using the commandline-tool are:

```
Command:
PVRTexToolCLI -i in.png -o out.pvr -f <format> [-q <quality>] [-m <numberofmipmaps>]

Options:

format
bits    format      Cocos2d  Cocos3d  transparency
32   R8G8B8A8,UBN      y        y          y
16   R8G8B8,UBN        y        y          n        
16   R4G4B4A4,USN      y        y          y
16   R5G5B5A1,USN      y        y          y
16   R5G6B5,USN        y        y          n
16   A8I8,UBN          ?        ?          ?
8    A8,UBN            y        y          y
8    I8                ?        ?          ?
4    PVRTC1_4          y        *          y        
2    PVRTC1_2          y        *          y
4    PVRTC1_4_RGB      y        *          n
2    PVRTC1_2_RGB      y        *          n
4    PVRTC2_4          n        n          ?
2    PVRTC2_2          n        n          ?

? don’t know
* needs 9 mipmaps
y supported
n really :)

quality for PVRTC:

pvrtcfastest
pvrtcfast
pvrtcnormal
pvrtchigh
pvrtcbest



I'll update this table when needed
```